# Cartoon or anime in which gems turn into monsters

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

A cartoon in which gems turn into monsters. I remember a monster that can use vine whip and he had a horn he had a green gem, this is not Pokémon. The cartoon was based in magical world. In the first episode a girl steals a book. I believe this show was on cartoon network.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Take a look at my comment above because we're really going to need some more details. Was it a western cartoon? An Anime? What channel did you watch it on? When abouts? etc.

Comment: Lol i think it was in the year 2009

Comment: That sounds awfully like Steven Universe to me

Comment: Or like [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144597/anime-with-gems-that-can-summon-beasts-to-fight-for-the-user-one-is-a-purple-tu).

Comment: @Rokuto I think you've got it, the horned creature is Ugger who has a "root whip" ability.

Comment: Green gem, horned plant monster, magical world, girl stealing a book... Yep, looks like the 1st episode of Magi-Nation, though it was never shown on Cartoon Network.

Comment: @Edlothiad You leave a comment and then immediately afterwards another one saying "Take a look at my comment above"? Why not just leave a single comment to begin with? Neither is close to the length limit.

Comment: @Randal'Thor if that breaks a rule, I'll never do it again. But it hardly seems like something that bad, when we have comments with "+1..."

Comment: @Edlothiad It's not breaking a rule; just seems weird is all. (Also makes your first comment - the same as you've left on many other questions - seem a bit botty.)

Comment: I can guarantee it's manually added every time. Although it's a standard copy pasted comment every time, it's manually added. I just added the details specific to the question because it seemed relevant in this case as a more obscure story-Id post

Comment: DistrubedNeo u are correct thanks and als to everyone