# Fantasy show where a kid uses crystals to summon creatures

Tags: story-identification, tv

Six or seven years ago I saw this show with a kid with brown hair that would use crystals to make creatures appear. They would have to go to a different world to do it.

One of the main monsters was a rhinoceros that could shoot vines and another like a big blue hairy dog.

Comment: Was this live-action or a cartoon?

Comment: It was a cartoon

Comment: Did it look like Japanese animation or was it more western cartoon-style? Realistic? Exagerated?

Comment: Probably the same one as this one: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144597/anime-with-gems-that-can-summon-beasts-to-fight-for-the-user-one-is-a-purple-tu/144602#144602

Comment: If it is, please confirm, and we'll close this as a dupe.

Answer (score 3):

Magi-nation. The rhino dude is Ugger and the blue dog is Furrok. It about a boy named Tony who went to the moon lands to help and save it.

Answer (score 3):

Magi-Nation it is an awesome show where the main character Tony is transported into a different dimension. He goes on a quest to same this dimension called the moon lands with Strag and Edyn. They are trying to stop the dark sorcerer Agram from escaping the core and taking over the world. The rhino is called ugger and the dog is furrok.

The show has two seasons and was created in 2008 and 2009 I think. It's used to be shown on TV4Kids every Saturday when they had the kids shows in the morning. I think it used to take the spot that huntik was in but eventually ended up after Yu-Gi-H 5Ds.