# Anime like pokemon but with crystals

Tags: story-identification, anime

There's an anime I watched around 2008 on Netflix, it's similar to Pokémon, but instead of Pokéballs, the main character has a green crystal that contains a blue moose-ish looking thing, it's like a bear with red antlers and blue fur. I remember an episode where the "gem world" (inside the gems where all the monsters are) was corrupted or infected or something. The main character sent the moose (that's what I'm calling it) back to the gem world, and the moose became infected and turned evil. In the last season, there was an episode where the villain opened up a gorge.

Comment: This is a good start, but is there anything else you remember? Are you sure about the date, and where you watched it? I didn't think Netflix was a thing back in 2008.

Comment: This sounds like it could be related to Stephen Universe - many episodes have dealt with Gems who were corrupted, and when defeated they are sealed in barriers (which could be remembered as similar to pokeballs).  I don't know if it's ever been on Netflix, though.

Comment: Not one of [these questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=anime%20crystal%20is%3aquestion)?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144597/anime-with-gems-that-can-summon-beasts-to-fight-for-the-user-one-is-a-purple-tu?

Answer (score 5):

Your answer is [Magi-Nation](http://magination.wikia.com/wiki/Magi-Nation_(TV_series)).

[image: Magi-Mation splash]

> The evil Shadow Magi, Agram, was sealed in the Core through the power of the Core Glyph and the eleven Dreamstones. Three thousand years later, his power has grown and threatens to destroy the Moonlands. To combat Agram, a human boy, Tony Jones, was summoned to fulfill a prophecy of the Final Dreamer and to join Edyn and Strag on a mission to follow the Book of Elders and collect the Dreamstones.

There was even a [pretty cool video game for this series](http://magination.wikia.com/wiki/Magi-Nation_(GBC)) that game out for the GBC.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Can you explain in more detail how this matches the description in the question? At the moment this answer is very short and likely to be deleted.