# Anime/cartoon: Tony and his 2 companions find the gems that fit into the legendary book

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

Tony, a boy from Earth, was running in a race and stopped to do his laces, is pulled over into the other world while his soon to be female companion tries to steal the book, thinking that she is the chosen one. But her master caught her and made her listen to reason.

Tony and the girl soon end up fighting people among their enemies. Tony has a rock which was given to him by his grandfather, he threw it as instructed by the girl and a blue beast that looks like a dog came. He helped them fight. The girl had her own one. Their other companion, male, also joined when the master told Tony about everything and what they had to do. They had to find the gems that fit into the legendary book.

I remember that once in the series they were up against a challenge in which there were multiple copies of the legendary book and they had to select only the authentic one. The girl remembered that she had spilt tea on some of the pages and thats how she recognized the book. Once those 3 even travelled to Earth and with Tony’s grandfathers ate pizza in a restaurant. They got to learn more about his grandfather and his connection to the other world.

I watched this very long ago on TV, maybe on POP TV or KIX TV, I don't remember but I really want to find this series.

Answer (score 4):

This is *Magi-Nation* (2007-2010).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magi-Nation_(TV_series)):

> Three thousand years ago in the Moonlands, the evil Shadow Magi Agram was sealed inside the planet's Core by the Core Glyph and the Dreamstones which provided its power. Now he plans to escape by using his Shadow Geysers to weaken his prison in order to bring the Moonlands under his control, and only a Magi known as the "Final Dreamer" can stop him. A young boy from Earth, Tony Jones, is summoned into the Moonlands as he is believed to be this Final Dreamer. He joins forces with the apprentice Magi, Edyn, and the Shadow Stalker, Strag, on a mission to gather the Dreamstones before Agram is set free. Using the Book of Elders, the three travel through the Moonlands while combatting the forces of Agram and gaining an ever-growing collection of Dream Creatures from the Moonlands that they visit.

You can see Tony summoning the "blue dog" (Furok) in the video below.

The book is the Book of Elders; per the [wikia](http://magination.wikia.com/wiki/Book_of_Elders):

> The Book of Elders is a book that was made by the elders of the Moonlands in order to trap Agram within the Core. The book gave clues to guide Tony, Edyn, and Strag to find the Dreamstones. Once all of the Dreamstones are inserted into the book's cover, the Core Glyph is formed and can imprison Shadow Magi in the Core.

You can see Edyn remembering she spilt tea on the authentic book in this scene.

Comment: If this is the right answer, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left :) and if so, it will be a duplicate of [Anime with gems that can summon beasts to fight for the user, one is a purple turtle](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/144597/98028)