# Netflix 2009-2012 animated TV show about a guy who uses runes to summon creatures in another world

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

There was this series on Netflix around 10 years ago about a child who had an ill grandfather.

He gets sucked into another world and has to collect runes which are like guardians and has monsters that are summoned from runes. I remember the monsters are more beast-themed and he was accompanied by a female, however the last gem/rune was in the other world.

There was also this book that they put the gems from the guardians into, and in one of the episodes they have to identify the right book and they do it by finding a coffee stain on it.

It’s not *Yu-Gi-Oh*, *Digimon*, *Shadowhunters*, *Monster Rancher* or *Di-Gata Defenders*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *Magi-Nation* (2007).

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1001475/):

> Three thousand years ago in the Moonlands, the evil Shadow Magi Agram was sealed inside the planet's Core by the Core Glyph and the Dreamstones which provided its power. Now he plans to escape by using his Shadow Geysers to weaken his prison in order to bring the Moonlands under his control, and only a Magi known as the "Final Dreamer" can stop him. A young boy from Earth, Tony Jones, is summoned into the Moonlands as he is believed to be this Final Dreamer. He joins forces with the apprentice Magi, Edyn, and the Shadow Stalker, Strag, on a mission to gather the Dreamstones before Agram is set free. Using the Book of Elders, the three travel through the Moonlands while combating the forces of Agram and gaining an ever-growing collection of Dream Creatures from the Moonlands that they visit.

What you remember about the coffee stain is from episode 25 (taken from [its wikia page](https://magination.fandom.com/wiki/The_Forum_of_the_Elders)):

> In the final test, Edyn needs to find the right book out of several. At first, she is unsure which one but then remembers **the real book has a tea stain in it thanks to her.**

---

I found it by remembering​ the same memory of spilt tea had came up on this very site, and I was involved somehow. I was sure it was *Huntik*, but when further research on Google found no match, I veered towards *Magi-Nation* as the two of them are the most misremembered "summon monsters" animes. Google brought the wikia page instantly, and with the anime's name it didn't take me long to find the question I remembered, namely [Anime/cartoon: Tony and his 2 companions find the gems that fit into the legendary book](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/197444/), which I did indeed answer.

Comment: Accepted answer at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144597/anime-with-gems-that-can-summon-beasts-to-fight-for-the-user-one-is-a-purple-tu