# 2000s anime/cartoon where they throw vials that hit a surface and summon beasts

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

Back in the early 2000s I'd watch Channel Go I believe and there was an anime/cartoon that would have a main character trying to find his dad.

A doctor/his dad made vials which the main character would use to fight and throw. The vials were mainly blue and red.

The main character's main fighting beast, I think, was a large white bear named Loki?

Comment: You have a good start here, but could you please take a look through [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and see if there are any other details you can remember? No detail is too small

Answer (score 4):

*Monsuno* matches, but it's from 2012.

From [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/anime/13185/Juusen_Battle_Monsuno):

> Chase Suno and his friends, Jinja and Bren, are on a search for Chase's father, Jeredy Suno. However, they soon become involved in something else upon reaching their father's lab and becoming involved with an organism known as Monsuno. Chase, choosing to side with his father's work, denies S.T.O.R.M. access to the Monsuno and escapes. They are now on the run from the military organization, S.T.O.R.M., while still looking for Chase's father. However, a mysterious organization also has his eyes set on Chase and the group's Monsuno.

There's a blue and white bear named Lock, which you might have confused with "Loki". The video below shows its summoning, which is done by throwing a blue cylinder on the floor.

Remembered from [Anime like Pokemon but blue cylinders instead of pokeballs and a creature that was a giant white bear with blue crystals on its back](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/205172/).