# Show like Pokémon, with three teens finding a bear with crystals in a jungle lab

Tags: story-identification, tv

When I was younger I watched this show on Hulu. I would like to find it.

I think the first episode went like this: three teens were in a jungle and found one kids dad's lab, and found a bear that fused with crystal. An organization with a black and yellow color scheme comes in and tries to take it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. I'm assuming this was animated? And in roughly which year did you watch it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Monster summoning" (since it is Pokémon-like) and "bear with crystals" makes me think of *Monsuno* (2012).

From [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/anime/13185/Juusen_Battle_Monsuno):

> Chase Suno and his friends, Jinja and Bren, are on a search for Chase's father, Jeredy Suno. However, they soon become involved in something else upon reaching their father's lab and becoming involved with an organism known as Monsuno. Chase, choosing to side with his father's work, denies S.T.O.R.M. access to the Monsuno and escapes. They are now on the run from the military organization, S.T.O.R.M., while still looking for Chase's father. However, a mysterious organization also has his eyes set on Chase and the group's Monsuno.

The gallery of [the Wikia page of the first episode](https://monsuno.fandom.com/wiki/Clash) provides pictures of:

- the lab in the jungle,
- the white bear with blue crystals,
- the bad guys with yellow/black uniforms

[image: Three youngsters standing in the jungle, in front of a door in some hill]

[image: White bear with blue crystals fused to its body]

[image: Crowd of baddies in a black uniform with yellow symbols]

---

Remembered from my own answer to [2000s anime/cartoon where they throw vials that hit a surface and summon beasts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/239478/).