# Show where beasts are stored in capsules and a girl had a polar-bear-like beast

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

So I can't remember too much but I know it was on TV in 2013 and they had little capsules or something to store their beasts and when they'd use them they would go big and they would ride them and I think a girl had a big polar bear like beast.

Comment: Can you confirm whether this is animated or live-action? (The [revision history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/262434/revisions) for this question shows that the cartoon tag was added by another user.) Also, what colour was the girl's hair, and can you describe the appearance of any other human characters (especially age, sex, and hair colour)...?

Answer (score 3):

Might this be ***[Monsuno](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1579911/)*** (2012-2013)...?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsuno):

> *Monsuno*, released as *Jūsen Battle Monsuno* (Japanese: 獣旋バトルモンスーノ, Hepburn: *Jūsen Batoru Monsūno*) in Japan, is an animated series that premiered in the United States on February 23, 2012 on Nickelodeon's sister channel, Nicktoons and began airing on TV Tokyo in Japan in October 2012, with global launches staggered by country sometime between mid-2012 and early 2013 through Nickelodeon. The series was created by Jeremy Padawer and Jared Wolfson. It is distributed by FremantleMedia and is produced by Dentsu Entertainment USA (part of Dentsu Aegis Network), Jakks Pacific, and The Topps Company. Japanese animation studio Larx Entertainment animated the series.

From [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/anime/13185/Juusen_Battle_Monsuno):

> Chase Suno and his friends, Jinja and Bren, are on a search for Chase's father, Jeredy Suno. However, they soon become involved in something else upon reaching their father's lab and becoming involved with an organism known as Monsuno. Chase, choosing to side with his father's work, denies S.T.O.R.M. access to the Monsuno and escapes. They are now on the run from the military organization, S.T.O.R.M., while still looking for Chase's father. However, a mysterious organization also has his eyes set on Chase and the group's Monsuno.

The show features beasts contained within small cylinders, including one somewhat resembling a polar bear, although that beast, [Lock](https://monsuno.fandom.com/wiki/Lock), is controlled by the lead character, a boy named [Chase Suno](https://monsuno.fandom.com/wiki/Chase_Suno). There is a girl in the group, named [Jinja](https://monsuno.fandom.com/wiki/Jinja).

Comment: If so, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205172/anime-like-pokemon-but-blue-cylinders-instead-of-pokeballs-and-a-creature-that-w