# Anime/Cartoon where the protagonist finds a lost gem which awakens a red, gold and white lion

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

I watched this anime/cartoon show on Nickelodeon Sonic, Disney XD or Jetix. There's this boy in some faraway land who discovers a lost gem and awakens a big, ancient beast, which looks like a red, gold and white colored lion. Further, the boy encounters several other such beasts whom he duels with his lion, using a variety of different colored gems.

Comment: Possibly a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/221348/anime-tv-show-with-gems-that-summon-beasts

Answer (score 1):

It might be *[Zinba](https://myanimelist.net/anime/31427/Zinba)*, a Vietnamese show.

[image: Front cover of Zinba]

> The juvenile Kan from the earth is summoned to the Kingdom of Toria , where he encounters attack from the giant creature Zinba, and he's rescued by the linker Shibuki and Uranus. Later, he accidentally gets on the linker squad DUX truck to the maze valley, finding in a cave a golden Zinba.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by [edit]ing it to explain why you think this might be the correct show, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question. It'd help the rest of us to decide how likely this answer is to be correct, and whether we should therefore upvote it or not.