# Boy is transported into another world via a crystal and gets a lion familiar

Tags: story-identification, tv, magic, cartoon

All I really remember about this cartoon was that the mc was a boy who was running by the woods when he comes across a crystal. he touches it and get transported to another world where the crystal turns out to be a magical blue lion that I think used to belong to his missing father or grandfather? And the mc is lowkey famous through his lion familiar. He makes two friends, a boy and a girl who are both from the magical world (and I think everyone has a magical familiar that can turn into crystals).

And if I remember correctly there was this episode where the mc is starting to see things from the human world. Like for example the group is walking and the mc thinks he sees a car coming towards them and throws he friends out the way and the friends are confused when the mc said a car was coming because they don't know what cars are. Then later in the episode the mc really does end up in the human world and his friends come to him to get him back into the magical world, or something like that.

I don't really remember anything else except for bits and pieces that most definitely don't help me find out what this show was called. But I think it used to be on netflix and it's name was a weirdly spelt version of magic, like magix or something.

Comment: From the title, I was expecting this to be about Steven Universe. But that Lion is *pink*, and belonged to his missing *mother*.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144597/anime-with-gems-that-can-summon-beasts-to-fight-for-the-user-one-is-a-purple-tu

Answer (score 3):

This is [Magi-Nation](https://magination.fandom.com/wiki/Magi-Nation_%28TV_series%29). Here you can see the crystals:

[image: three main characters with their creatures]

Answer (score 2):

Could this be [*Magi-Nation*](http://toonrific.pazsaz.com/maginat.html) (2007-8)?

> Magi-Nation follows the adventures of teenager Tony Jones, whose world is forever changed when he is mystically transported into a beautiful world far beyond imagination that was created a millennia ago by a powerful race known as the Magi.

[image]