# Anime in which the hero is a kid and his ace monster is a lion who becomes a giant when the hero throws a gemstone in its head

Tags: story-identification, anime

Here's what I remember:

- The gemstone was dropped by a guy in the forest who was carrying a big bag full of other gemstones that summon other monsters by the same way (putting the gemstones in the monsters' heads).  The kid saw the gemstone and used it.
- The hero and the lion fought many battles against lots of monsters.
- I remember that one battle was against a two-headed snake.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my question

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PowerCrystal - One of these, perhaps

Comment: Magi-Nation; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/222274/boy-is-transported-into-another-world-via-a-crystal-and-gets-a-lion-familiar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is *[Zinba](https://myanimelist.net/anime/31427/Zinba)*.

> The juvenile Kan from the earth is summoned to the Kingdom of Toria , where he encounters attack from the giant creature Zinba, and he's rescued by the linker Shibuki and Uranus. Later, he accidentally gets on the linker squad DUX truck to the maze valley, finding in a cave a golden Zinba.

Definitely involves monsters, including one resembling a jungle cat, with gemstones on their foreheads. Also, the first episode has the scene you described with a boy (the protagonist) picking up a gemstone that fell out of a guy's bag at around the 17:30 mark. And yes, the cat is small like a lion cub without the gemstone, but grows into a giant beast with the gemstone attached.

Comment: The lion had a hole in the head shaped like the gemstone (before the hero puts the gemstone in its head to boost his power )

Comment: The hero or the other characters (with different gemstones )throw the those gemstones at the monsters' forehead to give them their power.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: It was zinba 

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I wonder if the title is a nod to Simba of _The Lion King_. The cat itself is the titular _Zinba_ in this show.