# Cartoon - Main character transported to another world while running a track race

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I remember watching this a few times actually but it was a while back. I remember that the main character was transported to another world while running a track race by the ring his grandpa gave him. The Exposition of this show is like the other world is in peril from an evil person that used dark monsters. I also remember these monsters come from magical stones. The MC has a group of 3 including himself that are trying to fill a book with these stones.

Comment: How long ago was "a while back"? Was this on TV? What channels did you watch then? What kind of racing was it? Drag race? Laps? Demolition derby?

Answer (score 4):

Pretty sure this is *[Magi-Nation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magi-Nation_(TV_series))* (2007-2010).

> Three thousand years ago in the Moonlands, the Shadow Magi Agram was sealed inside the planet's Core by the Core Glyph and the Dreamstones which provided its power. Now he plans to escape by using his Shadow Geysers to weaken his prison in order to bring the Moonlands under his control, and only a Magi known as the "Final Dreamer" can stop him. **A young boy from Earth, Tony Jones, is summoned into the Moonlands as he is believed to be this Final Dreamer. He joins forces with the apprentice Magi, Edyn, and the Shadow Stalker, Strag, on a mission to gather the Dreamstones before Agram is set free. Using the Book of Elders**, the three travel through the Moonlands while combatting the forces of Agram and gaining an ever-growing collection of Dream Creatures from the Moonlands that they visit.

The first episode shows a boy being given a jeweled ring by his grandfather, and later being transported to another world while participating in a footrace. He then meets another boy and a girl in the other world, who have a magic book and wield magic stones that can summon monsters.

This series has previously been asked about and IDed [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144597/anime-with-gems-that-can-summon-beasts-to-fight-for-the-user-one-is-a-purple-tu).

Comment: @IC3 - If anyone correctly identifies the cartoon you're looking for, please mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Thanks.

Comment: And if so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144597/anime-with-gems-that-can-summon-beasts-to-fight-for-the-user-one-is-a-purple-tu?noredirect=1&lq=1