Animated TV show with a boy named Mikey and animatronic creatures like the Transformers
Trying to find a childhood animated TV show. The show starts off with a boy named Mikey (might be a nickname in the show), who is walking with his friends near a building. He hears something calling out for help but still walks off (I think he walks off without the creature). After a bit, he hears yelling, and his friends go to check it out.
A building was on fire, and there was a huge commotion. It was strange because there was a car stuck in the building, and as soon as Mikey and his friends got there, the car fell on them. All of a sudden, the creature jumps in and saves them while transporting them to another world. This creature is red and looks like an animatronic or like those Transformers characters. Because the creature was weak, it was very small; its normal form is small, and transforming makes it bigger.
The creature saved their lives in return for them to help their world from bad "animatronics." There are also regions, but I don't remember much of that. I also don't know if they ever return, but they basically go on journeys to these different regions and try to fight back against these bad "animatronics."
There's also a specific episode I remember that was near the end of the show, I believe. It was when they were in enemy territory and got caught. They told the enemy they were looking for the boss of the place, so they took them to him. The boss said something, and then they had a cooking battle. The kitchen was huge, like ginormous compared to them. The animatronics weren't all that big, so they could make up for their size with their strength. One of the friends steps up and starts baking and cooking for the judges to judge. The whole team gathers ingredients in the huge pantry their enemy has and gives them to the friend. The whole episode is about baking, and I'm not sure of the result of the cooking contest, but I know they got out of there alive.
I'm also not sure how many people are actually with Mikey (I think 3? Maybe 2), but I know the person who stepped up was a girl in the cooking competition. The red creature helping Mikey is also very popular in their world and has a lot of friends. Overall, it has a significant role in their journey, helping Mikey a lot through the hardships he faces. Also, I'm not sure if Mikey has any powers or if he goes into the animatronic for him to help.
I watched it probably during 2016-2018, and it was relatively new. I'm not sure where I watched it; I think it was Netflix, though (might be wrong).
Thank you if you're able to find anything!
(Also, the creatures in this world look similar to Pokémon but are a little different and have human-like eyes, I think [at least the red creature does]. The red creature looks similar to Pikachu (I don't think the red creature has any tail, not sure).
In the beginning of the show, when they get transported, they get attacked as soon as they get there. There aren't any other humans in this world as well.

Possibly a dupe of this: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/276506/what-animated-show-from-netflix-had-a-boy-go-to-another-world-and-meet-a-little (the answer to that question was Digimon Fusion).

And there is a cooking episode as per http://digimon.firstagent.net/2014/07/fusion-episode-27-sweets-zone-bake-off.html

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

As noted by Showsni, this might be Digimon Fusion, the answer to What animated show from Netflix had a boy go to another world and meet a little red monster with one horn.

The story begins with a seventh grade teenager named Mikey Kudo dreaming of commanding a Digimon army. The next day Mikey is harassed by his childhood friend named Angie Hinomoto over standing her up to help the basketball team and his rival named Jeremy Tsurgi demanding a kendo rematch. Mikey spots a dying red creature flickering in static. Wanting to save the creature, Mikey hears a mysterious voice. The mysterious voice presents him with a Fusion Loader. The Fusion Loader absorbs the creature to heal him within the item as Mikey grabs it against his friends' pleas. Mikey, Angie, and Jeremy are then sucked into a portal. They find themselves in a strange world surrounded by a hostile platoon of Digimon under MadLeomon. Mikey, Angie, and Jeremy are rescued by Ballistamon, Starmon, and the Pickmonz before the red creature emerges from the Fusion Loader. The red creature introduces himself as Shoutmon while stating his intent to become the Digimon King of the Digital World. After Shoutmon and his companions fight back against MadLeomon’s troops, MadLeomon absorbs his remaining forces to become Armed MadLeomon. Mikey helps his Digimon friends by using his Fusion Loader to DigiFuse Shoutmon and Ballistamon into an incomplete Shoutmon ×3/x4. After injuring Armed MadLeomon prior to reverting to his usual self, Shoutmon uses the DigiFused Starmon and Pickmonz, in the form of the Sun Sword, to defeat MadLeomon while forcing him back to his original form. A portal then appears. MadLeomon and his minions are recalled by their master named Tactimon. Tactimon is seen conversing with the other evil Digimon over the new turn of events. As Mikey and his friends learn that they are trapped in the Digital World, Mikey, Angie, and Jeremy agree to help Shoutmon and his Digimon friends. Mikey, Angie, and Jeremy are watched from afar by two other groups.

Opening Theme



There was a cooking episode, where Angie steps up to compete in an Iron Chef parody.

Though initially enamored with the Zone's confectionery-based construction, the Fusion Fighters quickly notice the empty streets, and Spadamon explains how the Zone's chefs were essentially imprisoned by the Zone's lead invader, Matadormon, and forced to cook for him. Spadamon also explains that Matadormon only accepts pastry chefs into his base. At that point, they are caught by the Bagra Army's Monzaemon patrols, but Mikey bluffs them by hyping Angie as a famous pastry chef. The Monzaemon allow them into Matadormon's fortress, which allows Nene, acting separately from the main group, to sneak her Monitamon in as well.
While Nene searches for the pastry chefs, Angie deals with a challenge from Matadormon's head pastry chef, GigaWaruMonzaemon. Though he sabotages their efforts, they manage to succeed, as Nene frees the pastry chefs. In an audience with Matadormon, they reveal their desire to overthrow him, but Matadormon fends them off and sends a powered-up GigaWaruMonzaemon to face them. Mikey responds with Shoutmon X4 who's too slow to deal with GigaWaruMonzaemon's rapid attacks. Seeing this predicament, Spadamon offers himself for a DigiFuse, forming Shoutmon X4S, who defeats GigaWaruMonzaemon.

Behold, GiaWaruMonzaemon!



