# TV show similar to Digimon, featuring some kind of lion/feline with a red mane and blue eyes

Tags: story-identification, tv, animated-series

In the show, I think they summoned the creatures using cards, or at least the obtained them like that. I remember a dragon [Agumon](https://digimon.fandom.com/wiki/Agumon) type of partner that like donuts (Spanish dub) or some sweet. There was also a creature that was some kind of lion/feline with a red mane and blue eyes (the entire eye). And at some point in the story, a huge tree is the scenery (not that confident about this one). It may have been only aired in Spain.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Approximately when did you watch this?

Comment: I don't remember exactly but I would say 2012? Maybe around that period?

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Might it be [*Magi-Nation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magi-Nation_(TV_series)) as per [Anime with gems that can summon beasts to fight for the user, one is a purple turtle](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144597/anime-with-gems-that-can-summon-beasts-to-fight-for-the-user-one-is-a-purple-tu?noredirect=1&lq=1)?

> Three thousand years ago in the Moonlands, the evil Shadow Magi Agram was sealed inside the planet's Core by the Core Glyph and the Dreamstones which provided its power. Now he plans to escape by using his Shadow Geysers to weaken his prison in order to bring the Moonlands under his control, and only a Magi known as the "Final Dreamer" can stop him. A young boy from Earth, Tony Jones, is summoned into the Moonlands as he is believed to be this Final Dreamer. He joins forces with the apprentice Magi, Edyn, and the Shadow Stalker, Strag, on a mission to gather the Dreamstones before Agram is set free. Using the Book of Elders, the three travel through the Moonlands while combatting the forces of Agram and gaining an ever-growing collection of Dream Creatures from the Moonlands that they visit.

[image]