# 2010's cartoon about a boy who meets this like blue tiger-like animal and ends up having to save an alternate world

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, isekai

I'm looking for a cartoon that I grew up watching, from like the 2010's.

It's a show about a boy who meets this like blue tiger-like animal that was bonded to his grandfather or something and ends up having to save this alternate world. He travels back and forth between the worlds by like a portal in a tree or something.

Sorry, I know it's not very specific, but I was young and don't remember a whole lot about it.

Comment: Did you watch this on TV? And was the animation hand-drawn or computer-generated?

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Magi-Nation](https://magination.fandom.com/wiki/Magi-Nation_(TV_series))*

[image: Splash image for the show]

> The evil Shadow Magi, Agram, was sealed in the Core through the power of the Core Glyph and the eleven Dreamstones. Three thousand years later, his power has grown and threatens to destroy the Moonlands. To combat Agram, a human boy, Tony Jones, was summoned to fulfill a prophecy of the Final Dreamer and to join Edyn and Strag on a mission to follow the Book of Elders and collect the Dreamstones.

He received the ring that lets him travel to the Moonlands from his grandfather.

### Opening

Comment: If so, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144597/anime-with-gems-that-can-summon-beasts-to-fight-for-the-user-one-is-a-purple-tu

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: No worries. We get a lot of people searching for this one. It must have made an impression.